# Объясните, что делает этот сервис провайдер (laravel 5.0) и как его перевести на laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Перевожу проект с Laravel 5.0 на Laravel 5.5. Проект не мой. В нем есть сервис провайдер, который называется BusServiceProvider (точно с таким же названием, сервис провайдер, есть и в Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider). В нём реализован только метод boot.Код в нем следующий

```
    public function boot(Dispatcher $dispatcher)
{
    $dispatcher->mapUsing(function($command)
    {
        return Dispatcher::simpleMapping(
            $command, 'App\Commands', 'App\Handlers\Commands'
        );
    });
}
```

Не могу понять, что делает этот сервис провайдер и при попытке просто задублировать код в новом проекте (где версия 5.5) методы mapUsing и simpleMapping не найдены.

Answer (score 2):

В версии 5.2 отказались от такой реализации, для поддержки это реализации воспользуйтесь пакетом [LaravelCollective/bus](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/bus).

Инструкция с переводом:

1) Удалите `Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider` с файла `config/app.php`.

2) Добавьте `Collective\Bus\BusServiceProvider` в файл `config/app.php`.
Если использовали для подсказок `Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher`, замените на  `Collective\Bus\Dispatcher`.

Есть ещё нюансы, описаны по ссылке выше.
Не факт что это вам поможет т.к. вы пропустили 5 релизов, нужно проходиться по каждому и по коду менять, то что вы сейчас исправите эту ошибку не значит что заработает сайт полностью.

Списки по которым стоит пройтись:

1) [Обновление до версии 5.1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.11)

2) [Обновление до версии 5.2 с версии 5.1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0)

3) [Обновление до версии 5.3 с версии 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0)

4) [Обновление до версии 5.4 с версии 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade#upgrade-5.4.0)

5) [Обновление до версии 5.5 с версии 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade#upgrade-5.5.0)

И вот только тогда можно сказать что сайт заработает, но это только фреймворк, нужно ещё учитывать что дополнительные пакеты тоже изменялись в зависимости от версий, и с ними тоже нужно сделать тоже самое.

Comment: ну по сути я поднял новый проект и туда потихоньку перевожу код. Просто я вообще не могу понять, что конкретно этот код делал раньше и стоит ли его переносить

Comment: Судя по коду консольные команды привязывает, в 5.5 уже это делают простым импортом, можно просто посмотреть как в 5.5 сделано и проверить совместимы ли ваши команды.